# как изменить значение в таблице?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот форма, при добавлений новой группы индикаторов в таблицу добавляется новая запись и выводится вместе с кнопкой "изменить".Как мне изменить запись напротив этой кнопки БЕЗ НАПИСАНИИ КОНКРЕТНОГО НОМЕРА id записи

ВОТ КОД:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><h1>Добавление новой группы индикаторов</h1></div>
    <div class="SignUp">
        <form action="indicator_group.php" method="POST" name="insert_indgroup"> 
            <div class="container">
            <input type="text" name="indicator_group_name" placeholder="Введите имя новой группы индикаторов">
            </div></br>
            <div class="container">
            <button class="SubmitStyle" name="Add">Добавить/Показать</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        include_once("Connectdb.php");
            if(isset($_POST['Add']))
            {
                    if($_POST['indicator_group_name']!='')
                    {
                    $Name_Group=($_POST['indicator_group_name']);
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO indicator_group (indicator_group_name) VALUES ('$Name_Group')");
                    }
                    echo"<table border=1>";
                    $query="SELECT * FROM indicator_group";// SQL-запрос
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    echo"<tr><th>Имя группы</th><th>Редактировать</th></tr>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo"<form><tr><td>".$row['indicator_group_name']."</td><td>"."<button type='submit' formaction='indicator_group_edit.php' formmethod='POST' name='indicator_group_edit_button' value=".$row['indicator_group_id'].">Изменить</button>"."</td></tr>"."</form>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysql_close();
            }
    ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Здесь я добавляю данные в таблицу под названием "indicator_group" и сразу же вывожу результат добавления.Перехожу на страницу обработчика "indicator_group_edit.php" и не знаю как осуществить добавление через другую форму как описывал выше, надо добавить запись в таблицу без указания ID номера. Помогите пожалуйста если кто знает как это осуществить.

Comment: Вы ошиблись годом, такое "модно" было писать в 80-ых. Я не понял сути, но без ID или другой уникальной информации, удалить точечно невозможно.

Comment: я только начинаю изучать этот язык и может и могу ошибаться.Суть программы, мне надо добавлять название определенной группы в базу данных phpmyadmin .Данные добавляются все работает кроме изменения записи как мне можно изменить запись?